# php string in to javascript code with comma except last string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm using a javascript plugin this is the line which I need help from u

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $('ul#news').newswidget({ source: ['http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/us', 'http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world', 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml'],
```

I would like to add URL data from MySQL
I'm using it with while loop like this

```
     $('ul#news').newswidget({ source:[<?php
while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
     echo "'"."$rssrow[rss_name]"."'".",";
}
?>],
```

It doesn't work properly :(.
 I need to get like URL,URL,RUL like this.
that means no comma for the last one

any one please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just build the string and remove the last comma:

```
$result = '';
while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
     $result .= "'"."$rssrow[rss_name]"."'".",";
}

echo ($result != '') ? substr($result, 0, -1) : "''";
```

OR use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$result = array();
while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
     $result[] = $rssrow[rss_name];
}
echo "'" . implode($result, "','") . "'";
```

(both of these methods will output `''` if the result set is empty.)

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do that pretty easily by a simple reorganization:

```
if($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
    echo "'".$rssrow['rss_name']."'";
    while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
    {
         // note no quotes -- they are redundant
         // prepend the comma
         echo ","."'".$rssrow['rss_name']."'";
    }
}
```

It does make for an extra step for the reader, but it does have the benefit of not needing substring, a new array, or a flag.

Answer (score 1):

here is a little bit different approach:

```
<?php
$news = array(
'source' => array(
    'http://example.com',
    'http://example.com'
)
);
$news_json = json_encode($news);
?>

<script>
$('ul#news').newswidget(<?php echo $news_json; ?>);
</script>
```

another variation:

```
$url = array();
while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
    $url[] = '"' . $rssrow['rss_name'] . '"';
}
echo implode(',', $url);
```

Comment: Your second version looses the first entry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = "";

while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
    $urls.= "'$rssrow[rss_name]',";
}

echo substr($urls, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why no comment points out that you should definitely escape your output. If an entry contains a `'`, all solutions aside from Dmitry F’s first will break badly.

```
$('ul#news').newswidget({ source:[<?php
$arr = array();
while($rssrow = mysql_fetch_array($rss))
{
  $arr[] = '"' . str_replace('"', '\"', $rssrow['rss_name']) . '"';
}
echo implode(',', $arr);
?>],
```