# PHP doesn't echo text for last row

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I'm trying to write a relatively simple twitter query in php with result like this:

from:TravisBenjamin3 OR from:AshleyElisaG OR from:tncvaan ...

This code works accept it doesn't echo the second OR, also I don't want to display an OR on the last row.

```
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counter++;
echo " from:";
echo $row['twitter'];
if ($counter < count($row)) {
               echo " OR";
           }
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265545/php-string-in-to-javascript-code-with-comma-except-last-string/7265564#7265564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$counter++;
echo " from:";
echo $row['twitter'];
if ($counter < $rowCount) {
               echo " OR";
           }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$tweets = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tweets[] = $row['twitter'];
}
if(count($tweets) > 0) {
    echo "from:" . implode(" OR from:", $tweets);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($r = 0; $r < $count; $r++)
{
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
   echo " from:";
   echo $row['twitter'];
   if ($r < ($count - 1)) 
   {
           echo " OR";
   }
}
```

Or, even easier:

```
$search = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $search .= " from:" . $row['twitter'] . " OR";
}

// Cut the last " OR"
$search = substr($search, 0, strlen($search) - 3);
echo $search;
```

Which is actually a poor man's implementation for implode() suggested by Aaron W..

Comment: There really isn't a need to change it to a for loop. Also, you have a `{` instead of a `;` after your fetch array.

Comment: A while loop with a counter pretty much equals a for loop, though the intent of the latter is clearer imho.